# NHibernate - Anyone have success upgrading to IBM Client Access v5.9 and IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries v12?

Tags: nhibernate

I recently upgraded my client access v5.4 to the latest v5.9. However, now, when I make a call to flush() from NHibernate's session object, the output shows the proper update query but it blows up on me. After the call to flush--even though I'm in Visual Studio--the operating system asks me which debugger I would like to use. I've selected 2008 but then it tells me that the 2008 debugger is already connected.

Finally, I cancel out of the question but visual studio ends debug mode so it doesn't return a message. I even have the call to flush surrounded by a try/except and the debugger never shows my message.

This whole issue began after upgrading the Client Access/IBM.Data.DB2.ISeries. Any ideas where to start looking for a solution?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The Client Access (5.9) version installed the IBM.Data.DB2.ISeries.dll ADO.Net driver. This driver has a bug in it when calling the ExecuteNonQuery.

I installed the latest Client Access Patch and it fixed it.